# How do I upload a complete site to Google Sites?

Tags: google-classic-sites

How can I upload all files and pages I have locally up to Google Sites?

Right now I can use templates as per my own wish to add folders, sidebars, footers to annotate the site. I am *not* talking about this.

I already have the contents in my hand for the site. All the files (including index.html), the sub files, CSS files. All I need is a mechanism to upload all the files so that when this site is visited, the index.html file is loaded.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that directly. Per the article [Upload existing web pages](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90558):

> You can't however upload web pages as individual HTML files.

Comment: Is this still the case, after 10 years?